# Need help using split function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This function adds up the numbers between zero in a string.  For example ('25025') becomes 25+25.  However, if I have a 0 at start and/or end of the string of the string argument being sent to test_string, it creates a space in the at the start/end of the list and won't compute.  What can I add to this function to make it filter out both 0s and blank spaces?

```
def test_one(test_string):
      test = test_string.split("0")
      numbers=[int(x) for x in test]
      print(sum(numbers))

test_one('2022022022')
test_one('02022020')
test_one('25025')
```

Comment: `numbers = [int(x) for x in test if x not in "0 "]`

Answer (score 2):

If you're ok with keeping your current approach, then this should do:

```
test = test_string.strip('0').split("0")
numbers = [int(x) for x in test]
```

Otherwise, you could use a comprehension in a generator expression altogether:

```
sum(int(x) for x in test_string.strip('0').split("0"))
#                                 ^
```

Comment: Wow, awesome!  That was really helpful and it makes sense.

Comment: This isn't quite right, it will break on a '00' or multiple repeated '0' sequence.  @ForceBru has the right answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
numbers=[int(x) for x in test]
```

With this:

```
numbers=[int(x) for x in test if x]
```

This code is self-explanatory: convert `x` to integer and append it to the list `if` `bool(x)` is `True`, thus *skipping all the empty strings*.

`str.split("0")` treats `"0"` as a delimiter and *doesn't* include any occurrences of it in the result. Check [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for some examples and more explanation.

Comment: This won't work because `"0"` is a non-empty string, making it `True`.

Comment: @joelgoldstick, fix what?

Comment: This is the correct answer, there won't be any '0' @joelgoldstick because he split on '0'

Comment: @joelgoldstick, you __split using `"0"` as a separator__, there won't be any zeros in the result

Comment: sorry, misunderstood

Answer (score 1):

You can use string one of methods *strip()/rstrip()/lstrip()*.

```
>>> s = '0138076023'
>>> s.lstrip('0')
'138076023'
>>> s.strip('0')
'138076023'
>>> s = '   asasd   '
>>> s.strip()
'asasd'
>>>
```

Docs about these methods can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.lstrip)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def test_one(test_string):
    test = test_string.split("0")
    print(test)
    if test[0] != '':
        numbers=[int(x) for x in test]
    else:
        test = test[1:]
        numbers=[int(x) for x in test]
    print(sum(numbers))

test_one('2022022022')
test_one('02022022022')
```

both  `test_one('2022022022')` and `test_one('02022022022')` will return the same

There've been a mistake on my side regarding case when string ends in zero. Made a correction.

Comment: that is based on how `split('0')` works - your test list gets `''` if your first digit is 0. So you just have to add a check in your function if the first element is zero in your string, or (which is same) check if the first element of `test` list is an emty string and kick it out if it is and then proceed as normal with your summation.

Comment: Why downvote? is there a mistake? Please show it to me then

Comment: unfortunately, there is one. If the input string will end on a zero, it'll get to the `else` part, and the first element of `test` will get cut regardless of its contents. For example, if `test_string=="2022020"`, the result will be `['22', '2', '']`

Comment: Better now. You can also do `test = test[1:]` (i.e. remove that `len(test)` which doesn't do anything useful here and may be time-consuming) and move `print(numbers); print(sum(numbers))` outside the `if/else` clauses for more code clarity, if you wish.

Comment: `test[1:len(test)]==test[1:]` is always `True`, so `len(test)` is redundant

Comment: @ForceBru, thanks for sharing experience. I have corrected, since someone may wish to use my solution once. Thanks again